# How to solve Carbon diffForHumans() time mismatch?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I use **Laravel 5.3**

for news create duration in Lravel blade tempate i use

```
echo \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($news->approved_at),'Asia/Dhaka')->diffForHumans()
```

but i get time mismatch.

**suppose approved_at = 2017-05-21 23:33:29**

after 5 minutes it show 5 minute ago but it show **4 hours ago**. i can not find the problem please help.

Comment: Can you give some more details about your application locale and the locale the user itself is using? What locale do you use in your `config/app.php` timezone setting?

Comment: GMT+6 is time zone and locale is 'en' @codedge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your timezone setting in `config/app.php` to

```php
'timezone' => 'Asia/Dhaka',
```

and then call `echo \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($news->approved_at))->diffForHumans()` without passing the timezone to Carbon.